# value of this inverse trigonometric expression.

Tags: trigonometry, inversive-geometry

How to evaluate this expression.
$$\sec^2(\tan^{-1} 2)+\csc^2(cot^{-1}(3))$$
I'm stuck on how to process squares, which is on sec and cosec function?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x=\tan^{-1}2$.  Then $\tan x=2$ and $\tan^2x=4$.  If $\tan^2x=4$, what does $\sec^2x$ equal?

Comment: $\sec^2 x=5$.Now i'll do it